# Avoid webview re-render web page on orientation change [Android]

Tags: android, webview, orientation

I am trying to avoid webview re-render web page on orientation change.

My activity is having fixed orientation as portrait, but on one button click I am changing orientation of the activity to landscape and portrait.

When I change the orientation of the activity then my web view takes time to render/refresh the page. My web page that web view is rendering is local and still it takes time (around 2-4 seconds) to display the contains of the page and i am seeing blank white screen in the transition time.

I tried to save the state of the web view by calling following functions:

```
 // Before switching calling
 Bundle webViewState;
 webViewState = new Bundle();
 Webview.saveState(webViewState);

 // When switching done then calling. 
 Webview.restoreState(webViewState);
```

But as mentioned in the android sdk docs we need to call these function in `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState` of activity cycle, so i am getting crash in this case as i am not calling these functions from activity cycle.

Does anyone have workaround/fix for this case.

UPDATE:
In my application i am using set orientation so i am not able to use `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState`, as these functions are not getting called when we have fixed orientation.

Answer (score 1):

Page is re-rendered because your activity is destroyed and recreated on orientation change. Update your activity in manifest:

```
<activity android:name="..."
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"  .../>
```

This will prevent system to recreate your Activity when orientation is changed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have a look in this section of the documentation: [Handling the Configuration Change Yourself](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange)

Comment: Thing is that my activity is having fixed orientation portrait, and because of that when i call `setOrientation` then my `onConfigurationChange` is not getting called. so i can't use this method. Is there anyway i can keep the orientation as gfixed and get onConfigurationChange event.. i don't think there is any way for it.

Comment: I think you'll need to share the code you're using to reorient the view. Everyone's going to assume you're talking about automatic system reorientations that destroy and recreate the activity and wonder why you can't call those methods from the lifecycle methods.

Comment: I have added update about this, please see my updated question.